# The requested URI is invalid for this FTP command

Tags: c#, .net

I have added the following code in my C#.net application in visual studio 2010

```
 WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("ftp://myftp.com");
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myusername", "12344");
            using (var resp = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(resp.StatusCode);
            }
```

But I am getting following error.

```
The requested URI is invalid for this FTP command.
```

Please suggest solution. Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you just want to check file information you should try changing the `request.Method` to `WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails` instead:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("ftp://myftp.com");
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myusername", "12344");
        using (var resp = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(resp.StatusCode);
        }
```

Comment: Hi, i just needed to check the FTP connection, came on this link. Works GREAT for me.... thanks skeryl and DotnetSparrow. :)

Answer (score 16):

Uri should be ftp:// + IP or ftpServerName + / Folder_to_create_Name

So, see follow code:

```
 WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("ftp://myftp.com/FOLDER_TO_CREATE/");
 request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.MakeDirectory;
 request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myusername", "12344");

 using (var resp = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
 {
       Console.WriteLine(resp.StatusCode);
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You must specify a sub-directory you wish to create; you can't create the root, which is what it appears you are trying to do. Hence the error.

Comment: I just want to connect to FTP and see which files are inside the directory at ftp